# ArduinoでWi-Fiモジュールを使用してPCへセンサーのデータを送りたい

Tags: arduino

[【Arduino】ESP-WROOM-02( ESP8266 )を使ってWifiで無線通信する](http://nn-hokuson.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/04/09/091148)

上記のURLを参考にESP-WROOM-02(ESP8266)というWifiモジュールを用いてArduinoからPCへセンサデータを無線で送ろうとしています。
しかし初期設定するときのコードを実行するためにURL先の回路図と同じように繋げると、Arduinoの電源が勝手に切れてしまいます。
5Vで接続すると電源が落ちてしまうようなので3.3Vで接続すると電源は落ちないのですが、初期設定のプログラムがうまく動作しません。
おそらく給電が足りずWifiモジュールとArduinoがうまく動作出来ていないのだと思います。

5Vだと電源が落ち3Vだと動作しない、いずれも原因はわかりません。
Arduinoや回路に詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。
URL先にありますが一応初期設定のコードを貼っておきます。
3.3Vで接続した場合シリアルモニタにはGoodnight moon! のみ表示されます。
こちらからATコマンドを入力してもOKが返ってこないので接続が出来てないんじゃないかと思います。

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() { // run over and over
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

追記

ご丁寧に回答有難うございます

配線をやり直したりレギュレータやコンデンサを挿し直したりすると、５V接続時でも電源が落ちないようになったので電源の問題は解決できたと思います。
しかし上のプログラムの結果が変わりません。
Goodnightmoon!だけしか表示されず後に出てくるはずのHelloworldが表示されず、UARTコマンドを送信してもレスポンスが帰ってきません。
シリアル通信に問題があるのでしょうか？
Arduino側の問題なのかWifiモジュール側の問題なのかよく分かりません。

Comment: 正しく接続できていないのわかっているなら、まずはそっちの修正から。あなたの実機が回路図通りでないに１票。こういう質疑応答の場では間違った情報からは間違った結果しか出ないわけで、実機配線から起こしなおした回路図（手書きで十分）が必要です。その回路チェックの際に誤りが見つかる可能性が大ってことで。

Comment: 「5Vで接続すると電源が落ちてしまうようなので3.3Vで接続する」というのが意味不明です。参考にしたサイトには、Arduinoから５Vの電源を得て、3.3VのレギュレータICで3.3Vにして、それをWiFiモジュールに供給するようになっています。ちゃんと回路図が理解できていますか？？？

Comment: コメント有難うございます。電源の問題は解決できたと思います。追記で別の問題点を挙げたのでそちらの方も何か分かることがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

質問の「Goodnightmoon!だけしか表示されず後に出てくるはずのHelloworldが表示されず」という部分ですが、該当部分のコードは以下のようになっていますから、"Goodnight moon!"はSerialに、"Hello, world?"はmySerialに、それぞれ出力されます。

```
  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
```

serialとmySerialが何に接続されているのか知りませんが、Serialのほうだけ表示されて、mySerialのほうが表示されないのだとすれば、「mySerial.begin(115200);」というSoftwareSerialの通信速度設定が、SoftwareSerialにつながっている機器の通信速度と不一致になっているのではないかと思います。

==

Comment: Arduinoには別のセンサが接続されていたので全て外しましたが、通信速度の不一致を直す方法が分かりません。具体的にどうすればいいでしょうか？Arduino初心者で分からないことばかりですいません。

Comment: 質問の初めにあるリンク先の"初期設定"のところに、「ArduinoとESP-WROOM-02間の通信はソフトウエアシリアル通信を使います。ESP-WROOM-02が初期状態では115200bpsで通信するのに対して、Arduinoのソフトウエアシリアルの最高速度は9600bpsです。　このままでは安定した通信ができないため、ESP-WROOM-02の通信速度を9600bpsまで下げる必要があります。」との説明があり、そのあとに通信読度を設定する手順が書かれていますよ。　せっかくリンクしたのですから、ちゃんと目を通したほうが良いです。

Comment: その初期設定のプログラムでHelloWorldが表示されません、手順に従ってレートを115200にしてますしCR及びLFにも設定してあります、リンク先の記述はこなしているつもりなのですがうまくいかないです・・

Comment: Arduinoのソフトウエアシリアルは9600bpsより早い通信速度にできません。「手順に従ってレートを115200にしてます」というのは、ソフトウエアシリアルが絶対に使えないように設定しているという事です。落ち着いてコメントや参考のページを読みましょう。日本語が判らないのなら、判る人に開設してもらいましょう。一人で問題を解決するのは困難だと思われますから、知っている人に頼りましょう。